# Drop database with special characters

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

While testing RoR, I created a database that is literally named  "<test_project>_development", so when I try to drop it through postgresql I get a syntax error because of the "<>" in the database's name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres uses quotes to delimit literal entity names:

```
drop database "<test_project>_development"
```

See [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).